# Is it possible to group messages like whatsApp app? If yes, how can I do it with FCM?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is it possible to group messages like whatsapp app?
If yes, how can I do it with FCM?

If You will get Notification one by one and only have one data payload.
In this case can you update current notification like Whats App?

I tried InboxStyle to group in one notification.

```
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new 
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID);

  mBuilder.setTicker(title);
  mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
  mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
  mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
  mBuilder.setGroup(group);
  mBuilder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
  mBuilder.setWhen(getTimeMilliSec());
  mBuilder.setContentText(message);
  inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
  inboxStyle.addLine(message);
  mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  notificationManager.notify("App Name", 5, mBuilder.build());
```

New Notification generated instead of adding received notification to current notification.

Comment: Please read the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group)